# Формат возвращаемых данных NSData.dataWithContentOfURL

Tags: swift, objective-c, ios

Здравствуйте.
От сервера получаю кириллический символ "а" (а-арбуз).

NSData возвращает -> d0b0

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком формате возвращаются данные и где найти таблицу соответствия для ручного сравнения.

Я честно пытался искать сам, но результаты поиска подсказывают, что я даже неправильно формирую поисковой запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри какая кодировка тебе возвращает, может быть UTF8

```
NSString *ss = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```